# Live Chat Servlet JSP application

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, chat

I was going through some Live Chat Plugin.

Actually, We already have Web Based application deployed on tomcat running fine.
Now need is to integrate Live Chat feature.

So was thinking and created some design that on FrontEnd I will use jQuery and on Server Side I will use BlockingQueue for incoming Chat Request and then process each request etc etc.

Later on I thought of like instead of doing it all from scratch I can go through some Plugin, There are many jQuery plugins but they all have their own Advertisement added to it. Also most of all are paid for commercial use.

So I came across XMPP Protocol.
I am not much clear on XMPP, does it can help me in developing such Application? 
I tried with WebSocket but it requires HTML 5 which restricts me to dig into more.

can some one suggest me proper and right approach for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If can use Java EE 7 then [Web Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm) are definitely a way. This technology was specifically designed to handle connection of multiple clients and their interaction on the web page. If you can't switch to Java EE 7, there are also other frameworks which can do the job like [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) or others, just take a look at the list which can be found [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Atmosphere-PlugIns-and-Extensions).

Comment: I read regarding webSocket. Consider I can switch to Java 7 still can't afford that it works only with HTML 5. Need some solution with Java 6.

Comment: I already wrote that in my answer, give Atmosphere a try:)There are already plenty of chat examples - https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/master/samples